# PHP $_SESSION's Not Working in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: php, session, session-variables, cloud9-ide

First timer on all fronts here. I've done my digging and I'm ready to post it. I can't seem to get my session variables to carry over. From what I've read, header(LOCATION:) can do some pretty wonky stuff and some code may not be done. session_start(); is at the top of every page. Heres page 1:

```
<?php
session_start();
include "/header.php";
$username = $_POST["user"];
$db = new SQLite3("../../database/login.db");
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);
$userquery = $db->querySingle("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE username='$username';");
$passquery = $db->querySingle("SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE username='$username';");
$loggedin = false;
```

I call the session variable here on the same page (1):

```
if ($loggedin == true)
{
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    header('LOCATION: ../test.php');
}
```

Then on the logged in page (2) the header references I have:

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php include "header.php";?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="dashboard.css" rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>
             Dashboard
        </title>
        <h1>
            Dashboard
        </h1>
        <h2>
            Greetings: <span><?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?></span> Today's date: <span><?php $date = date("l,F,N,Y"); echo $date;?></span>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something simple. Thanks everyone!

Comment: what happens if you add exit; after the header function call ? Also try to make it an absolute url in place of ../test.php .

Comment: something like this: header('Location: http://www.example.com/test.php');
exit;

Comment: Hey @Maximus2012 that was fast! I've tried adding exit(); and it did nothing. I didn't try creating the entire URL for the file. I'll give that a whirl now!</br>
[edit]edit:[/edit] I've just tried the long URL and it does not work still. I've also tried exit; instead of exit(); and still nothing.

Comment: Just sending an example of login using php session. See this one and can rectify anything you are doing or try to use this http://krisnaordinary.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/creating-a-simple-login-logout-session-using-php/

Comment: Seeing about it now @pal4life Thanks for the quick response as well! edit:wow i've read a bit and already found something he did differently. He posted those vars in the main login window.

Comment: I also tried his request statement instead of post. I'm not sure what the problem could be...

Comment: You can upvote the comment if that link was helpful. Also use http://codepad.org to paste your code to show whats going on there

Comment: it was definitely helpful, but all that i've learned from it didn't fix the issue. the other page is helpful as well. it just doesn't make any sense that the variables aren't carrying over from the login page. if i stop the code of the login page the variables work there but if i redirect they get lost in the nether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT!!
So I'm using cloud9 IDE and the PHP.ini file in use doesn't permit sessions. Now what I had to do was create my own PHP.ini file in the root project folder. This ini file overrides the one that cloud 9 defaults to which is only readable.
I hope this helps someone in the future!!!!!